# Issue with Browser mode and Document mode of IE

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I am having an issue with IE. I was testing my site for IE7 compatibility (I have IE9).

When I change both the Browser mode and the Document mode to IE7 then it shows all right (I checked in a different computer with IE7 installed, it shows the same effect as this).

But whenever I change only Browser mode to IE7 and keep the Document mode to say IE8 then the style goes bizarre. I went through some blogs which says that, if I change browser mode to IE7 then it forces the document mode to IE7 one. But I think the case is not the same here.

Am I testing correctly by changing both Browser and document mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actully if you have doctype html4 then you should have browser mode same and document mode is quirk.for example

browser mode - ie7 and document mode - quirk

and if you have doctype xhtml or html5 then your browser mode same and doctype same as well for example :

browser mode - ie7 and document mode ie7 standard

and doctype is should me same as the browser.

Comment: thank you for the information @sachin, do you have any link where I can find out why it is this way ?

Comment: sure will give u the link asap :)

Comment: here wo go http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28VS.85%29.aspx#bdmodes have a look on that